# How Can I Edit the Body of an API Request With a Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, http, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a firefox addon that modifies the body of a background http request to an api. I found [`webRequest.filterResponseData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData), but it did not work for my use case:

If I go directly to the api url, the response body gets changed by the filter.

If I go to the website that makes the request in the background as it loads, the filter doesn't change the response body. I debugged the addon and saw that the response was being sent to the loading page and only after that `filter.ondata` was called, so the filter had no effect.

Does anyone know how can I make sure the filter is applied before the api response is passed to the page being loaded?